# how to merge citation's sources while copying in WORD

Tags: microsoft-word

I have two word documents with citations to one common sources.xml file. When I copy text with a citation from one file to another, I've got two equal books in a sources list. So, now I have to change the inserted source in a copied text to the same source of this receiving file and delete this source in the sources list manually.
Why Word doesn`t merge equal sources, how to merge them?

Comment: *Why Word doesn`t merge equal sources* They are not equal. Their full names are different at least. And Word takes into account that one of the files (which are now "equal") can be changed at any time, while the other can remain unchanged or can be changed in a different way.

Comment: One file has a source say "Book 1 of author 1" it has tag "Book1", another file has the same source. You copy text with a citation on this book from one file to another. As a result, you have two equal books in sources list but with different tags, because Word changes copied tag automatically.